# jQuery:Looping all radio buttons inside an HTML table

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have an HTML table having n rows and each rows contain one radiobutton in the Row.Using jQuery , How can i look thru these radio buttons to check which one is checked ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#table tbody tr input[type=radio]').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

HTH.

Comment: `#table > tr` will choke on certain browsers (chrome/firefox) that like to add their own `tbody` elements, whereas `#table tr` won't.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do that, e.g., using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and the [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) traversal method:

```
$("table tbody tr td input[name=something]:radio").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("tr").css("border", "1px solid red");
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll give +1 if you can tell me if it is pretty well guaranteed that all (jQuery supported) browsers will reliably insert a missing `<tbody>`.

Comment: @patrick - No, that's not the case. Which means that my selector is broken some of the time. Which means I'll edit this answer now. Damn it, but thanks, I should pay more attention to my own answers in the future :)

Answer (score 4):

To loop through all the radio checked radio buttons, you can also do this:

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function() {
    //this loops through all checked radio buttons
    //you can use the radio button using $(this)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.my-radio-class:checked')
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to process every radio button or do you only need the checked ones? If the latter, it is quite easy:

```
$('table input:radio:checked')
```

Reference: [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/), [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: +1. Afaik jQuery's look-up goes from right to left, so the whole `thead tr td` is unnecessary if the only condition is that they need to be in a table. And `:radio` and `:checked` are the most ‘elegant’ selectors in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = $('#table :radio:checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table tr input[type=radio]:checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the checked radio input, put more specificity in the selector if needed
var $checkedRadio = $("input[type=radio]:checked");

//if you want the value of the checked radio...
var checkedRadioVal = $checkedRadio.val();
```